# Haskell: which SOAP client lib to use?

Tags: haskell, soap

I'd like to write s simple Haskell program that connects to a SOAP service. Ideally I'd like to use the service's WSDL and get as straightforward access to the request parameters and response data as possible.

What library do I use?

So far I only found [HAIFA](http://staffwww.dcs.shef.ac.uk/people/S.Foster/HAIFA.html) but it seems to have stopped developing around 2006, so I'm not sure if it's the right choice.

*Update 2015-08-14:* As of now, a package named [soap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/soap), along with protocol support packages [soap-tls](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/soap-tls) and [soap-openssl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/soap-openssl) is available on hackage and looks alive.

Comment: Tangent: general advice is to prefer REST over SOAP if at all possible. (If you do not control the service, then obviously this is not possible.)

Comment: @DanBurton: If I were writing a server, or otherwise had a choice, I would surely prefer REST + (JSON|XML). Unfortunately, I have a 3rd-party service to interface with.

Comment: I don't know of any good full-scale SOAP support in Haskell, sadly. I think that Haskell wasn't much of a serious web language when SOAP was in vogue, and now the world's largely moved on so there's never been a strong incentive for good SOAP support. For minimal SOAP, rather than the full beast, its easy enough to do your own thing with Haskell's very good XML libs.

Comment: So, how actually world's largely moved on? SOAP is actively used. Lots of enterprise solutions take great benefits by using SOA and integrating ESB systems in their products. SOAP closest alternative is REST, which is quite bad for really big solutions because of it's lack of service definition which includes full description of a service including operations, transport and type information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @sclv says, the SOAP heyday was before Haskell was seriously used for web systems. As a result your options for fully-fledged SOAP libs are somewhat restricted.

Obviously, [HAIFA](http://staffwww.dcs.shef.ac.uk/people/S.Foster/HAIFA.html) was the biggest effort back in the day, but it isn't on Hackage, so you're mostly out of luck there. Looks like [shoap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shoap) was a bit of an attempt at getting something simple working as well.

For rolling your own, there are plenty of [XML options to choose from on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html#cat:xml),

- HaXML,
- [haxr](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haxr)
- fancy "conduit"-style [xml parsing](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit)