# SOAP web services in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, soap, wsdl, rpc

I have to write a bunch of small web services. They must be defined by a WSDL and work via SOAP-RPC, in order to work with an existing workflow engine and service registry framework. I can, however, serve them on a service stack/platform of my choice.

I'm presently writing them in Java, and it's not too bad.  But I'm thinking my life might be easier if I was able to write these services in Haskell.  Searching on Google, it looks like, once upon a time, someone else had the same idea and started a project called "HAIFA".  However, it looks like HAIFA hasn't been maintained for some years, and I couldn't find any other frameworks supporting serving up services written in Haskell as SOAP web services.

Does anyone know of any other frameworks that will allow me to easily write SOAP-based web services using Haskell?

If not, has anyone done this manually (i.e., use XML libraries from hackage to process the incoming soap-rpc requests, and create soap-rpc compliant replies)?  Was it difficult to do? Any gotchas? Was it worth the effort?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931410/haskell-which-soap-client-lib-to-use

It seems you're out of luck here...

Comment: Why do you want to move away from Java, it has excellent support and libraries for web services (disclaimer, I don't use Java or even really like it, but for WS it's up there with C#).

Answer (score 6):

Since HAIFA is dead now there are no equivalent frameworks for SOAP web services in Haskell now. So I would advise you to use some bunch of frameworks.
May be Yesod + shoap will be suitable.
I think such a tendency in domain of SOAP WS frameworks in Haskell because of smooth transition to REST/JSON technologies.
Also may be these two articles will be useful for you
http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~haskell/hwsproxygen/files/HWSProxyGen.pdf
and
http://www.jofcis.com/publishedpapers/2010_6_9_2859_2867.pdf

Answer (score -1):

If you just need to send vanilla XML/SOAP messages then you could probably just open connections and read/write Aeson. But if the SOAP services need WS-Security, WS-Addressing, etc., support, you would be better off using an existing framework. For example: https://metro.java.net/

Disclaimer: I have been involved in Metro.

It would be great to have a SOAP framework in Haskell though.