# AWS lambda like execution of Haskell functions

Tags: haskell

In AWS Lambda people can create a node.js function and trigger it through events, for example a message, etc..

I wonder how this can work 'under the hood' and how to put something like this together in Haskell. The uploaded functions are basically single function libraries without any `main` function.

Means on the CLI or via an API you can call any of your functions by name (and with the required input) and you get the output defined by the function signature--or, alternatively an error of course.

Would it be possible to do this in Haskell?

To clarify: what I want to do is for example loading a number of different single function Haskell libraries on a Haskell platform or any other execution context that is in my data center and execute / call them by name via the CLI or an API just in the same way AWS Lambda works with node.js functions.

Comment: What are you looking for? May be https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aws-lambda

Comment: I look for some guidance how to put the execution of arbitrary functions in Haskell without a main function in practice. The Haskell aws-lambda package is a wrapper for the AWS API so that you can execute / trigger lambda functions within your haskell function.

Comment: I think you must to clarify what you want to do (write some AWS Lambda function using Haskell language is not possible) and, strictly, any program need the `main` function to work (although that function run into some service server). Do you want write AWS Lambda functions using Haskell? Then take a look to Amazon Linux...

Comment: Added a clarification. Hope this helps. I think if you have worked w AWS lambda it gets clear what look & feel I want to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

If you want reproduce the same functionality (functions as services) exists a lot of technologies you can use (soap, rpc, rest, ...). If you unknown it I suggest to you read about.

My ever favorite is SOAP but is so unpopular and Haskell support is limited [soap](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/soap) (see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931410/haskell-which-soap-client-lib-to-use)). SOAP (as others) provide exactly you want.

But you must to concrete your real problem to select the best technology.

If you are looking for distribute your own Haskell code [Cloud Haskell](http://haskell-distributed.github.io/) may be a good starting point.

If you need more like "web server" then take a look to [sodium](https://github.com/SodiumFRP/sodium), [elm](http://elm-lang.org/), ... in a Javascript style or [servant](https://haskell-servant.github.io/) (generate client code to some languages).

Anyway, even AWS Lambda require support for each language and you should not expect to find one ubiquitous technology (like HTTP) for RPC.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the "serverless for haskell" framework: http://qmu.li

Not only you can run individual haskell functions as Lambda functions with it but you can also describe your whole AWS infrastructure in haskell. (vs. doing it in CloudFormation json/yaml template), build it all locally and easily deploy to AWS.